# How to use DecompressionStream to decompress a gzip file using JavaScript in Browser?

Tags: javascript, typescript, web, vite, webapi

All major browsers now support the [DecompressionStream API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DecompressionStream), but I can't figure out how to use it with `fetch()` to decompress a gzip file in browser.

The following code works with a base64 string:

```js
const decompress = async (url) => {
  const ds = new DecompressionStream('gzip');
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const blob_in = await response.blob();
  const stream_in = blob_in.stream().pipeThrough(ds);
  const blob_out = await new Response(stream_in).blob();
  return await blob_out.text();
};

decompress(
  'data:application/octet-stream;base64,H4sIAAAAAAAAE/NIzcnJVyjPL8pJAQBSntaLCwAAAA=='
).then((result) => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

However, if I create a `hello.txt.gz` file using `gzip hello.txt` on MacOS (`hello.txt` is a plain text file with content "hello world"), then the function above throws an Error.

```
decompress('/hello.txt.gz').then((result) => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

```bash
# FireFox
Failed to read data from the ReadableStream: “TypeError: The input data is corrupted: incorrect header check”.
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The operation was aborted.

# Chrome
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

# Safari
[Error] Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: TypeError: Failed to Decode Data.
[Error] Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: Failed to Decode Data.
```

**Edit**

There is a reproducible demo at [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-vrvd2k?file=src%2Fmain.ts).

Comment: *"Failed to fetch"* - does the file accessible in the first place?

Comment: It indeed looks like you're just hitting a 404 or alike. Check you path and your network tab. Also, from an URL like that you don't need to go to a Blob and then extract a stream from it, nor to produce a Blob from the Response to then get a text from it, you can directly do `const stream_in = response.body.pipeThrough(ds); return new Response(stream_in).text()` https://jsfiddle.net/yv5wzsrt/

Comment: Thanks! @BagusTesa I added a demo at https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-vrvd2k?file=src%2Fmain.ts. The fetch response is 200.

Comment: Hi @Kaiido, I added a demo at stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-vrvd2k?file=src%2Fmain.ts . It seems the fetch response is okay (200).

Thank you so much for your example! It worked with my `hello.txt.gz` file! I will keep looking into it.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting, but no, the response is not ok. The server sends the Content-Type as "text/plain" and the Content Encoding as "gzip", and it doesn't pass any data. Somehow the `.gz` extension makes it trip out in thinking it's one of its own response or something like that. Change the extension of your file e.g. to `.bin` and it will work fine. I'm really not sure why the server behaves like that, and I'm not sure either if it's only a stackblitz issue or if it's a default config. Just tried on my localhost (almost bare apache config) and it works fine, so that'd be a stackblitz issue.

Comment: Wow I see, thank you so much @Kaiido!! ❤️❤️ Changing to `.bin` worked for me. I guess there is something weird going on with the Vite server. They might be pre-processing files with extension `.gz`...

Comment: @Kaiido Could you please add a short answer so I can accept it and close the problem? 

Comment: Related Vite issue: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/12266

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I don't really have time right now to compose an answer, and the GH issue you found would make a far better answer than what I could have written, so feel free to self-answer :-) (Ps: I added retrospectively the vite issue for discoverability since this is actually the source of the issue).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @kaiido's help (see question comments), we found that this error is caused by the Vite server. The development server serve `.gz` files with wrong headers.

```
"content-encoding": "gzip"
​​"content-length": "42"
"content-type": "text/plain"
```

A workaround is to rename the file to use a different extension (e.g., `hello.txt.gz` → `hello.txt.gzip`).

#### Related Vite Issues

- [Dev server should send pre-compressed static files without Content-Encoding: gzip #12266](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/12266)
- [Error when trying to serve tar.gz files from public directory #5183](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/5183)
- [Dev server serves GZipped JSONs with the wrong Content-Length header #6420](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/6420)